# How do I check another empire's FTL method?

Tags: stellaris

There are three different methods of FTL:

- Warp
- Hyperdrive
- Wormholes.

It's useful to know what method other empires use, for defense, etc. While it's easy to tell at a glance if they use wormholes (because of the presence of wormhole stations), is there a method to tell apart the others (without keeping a track of their ships)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't, you have to watch the movements of the foreign fleet. But here you have two options:

1. If you yourself use hyperspace, you can see the hyperspace lanes, if you don't, you can research a technology (hyperspace mapping) allowing you to do so, though it's a rare tech.
   Either way, once you can see the lanes, you can easily determine whether an empire uses hyperspace or warp by seeing whether they travel on the lanes or not. Or wormhole, if they don't travel at all, but simply appear.
2. Another factor is the cooldown time.
   Hyperspace and wormhole have a charge-up time before the jump, whereas warp has a cooldown after a jump. When a foreign fleet enters your system and you read something like "warp winddown" in their status window, they use warp. If they are able to move immediately, they use hyperspace or wormhole.
   But you can easily distinguish hyperspace from wormhole by the presence of wormhole stations and the fact, that wormhole fleets appear instantly in your system instead of travelling through space.

Comment: I would retract my upvote if I could. This is a possible method to figure it out, but as tanny's answer points out, if they're in sensor range you can actually just look at the ship and see.

Comment: This is incorrect, see the other answer. Go to the System view, hover cursor over the fleet, read the tooltip which spells out the drive technology. Alternatively you can click on them, then click "ship details" and look at the drive. Don't get confused by the comments on the other answer: there is no special sensor requirement, there only needs to be a ship so you can hover/click.

Comment: If something changed allowing other variants of detecting an empires drive method apart from those two answers, feel free to create an answer. I don't see the point in commenting on my answer over 20 months later, especially as pretty much the entirety of your comment is an addendum to the other answer. This question was posted literally days after the initial release of Stellaris and many game mechanics weren't that well explored back then, I didn't nkow you could check other empires designs back then and used the method described in my answer, which is still a valid method.

Answer (score 7):

When you click an enemy fleet, it has an information, then you click on one of the ship to view ship design. There is one slot of FTL engine that allows using it.

Bonus:
How to counter (this assumes that you have free transportation)

Warp Drive: Use space station (combat one) that bring enemy into the station then kill it quickly or at least make them less powerful before warp wind down.

If you're their friend, they won't have much trouble traveling except if they're surrounded.

Hyperspace: If you use hyperspace mapping, you may block their way if you're their foes, and heavily fortify it if you're their friend, then it would be 
a pleasure to allow their access or leave this system theirs.

Wormhole: Split your army and no matter where they came from if you can destroy their wormhole station they're stranded. If you're your friend station right might be good or they may never come to help protecting you. Also this wormhole make you can go pass any territory into system with station. If you're wormhole player you might build a strong economy by building everywhere with rich resources and still get connected.

Comment: The question wasn't about how to counter different drives, so only the part before "Bonus" is really relevant. It sounds like you're saying that you can just check their ships, which is a pretty good answer if it's true.

Comment: @DCShannon Yes indeed you can. Just need to have sensor range on the empire's ship.

Comment: I tried this, and it worked, but not in combat. And you do indeed need sufficient sensors on the ship.